# "no valid sudoers sources found, quitting" error while chmodding /var/www

Tags: permissions, sudo, ubuntu-11.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and just installed LAMP. I'm trying to paste files into the `/var/www/` directory so i can test my PHP projects, but I can't.

I have searched on the web and all I read is: "type `sudo chmod 077 /var/www/`" or something like that, but my machine throws back this:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0777, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is not reading what your machine "throws back". The problem is described in the very first line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem seems to be a bigger one. Try the following:

- Restart your computer
- Boot into Recovery Mode (select the "Recovery" option from the boot screen. If you're single-booting Ubuntu, you need to hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to get to the GRUB menu)
- At the prompt you see, select "Drop to root shell prompt"

  [image]
- At the command prompt (which should say `root@your-computer:~#`, enter:

  ```
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
  ```
- Then, restart your machine

  ```
    shutdown -r now
  ```

Now, you should be able to use `sudo` again. It seems you've tried a few wrong commands before.

---

**Note:**

Always take care that you know what you're doing when you use `sudo`.

**Another note:**

Running `sudo chmod 077 /var/www/` is definitely not what you want to do. If you want to set permissions on `/var/www`, it would be advisable to create a new group of users that have write-access to the directory.

```
sudo addgroup www-users
sudo adduser <your-username> www-users
```

Replace `<your-username>` with your real username. This will add a new group `www-users` and add yourself to it.

Then, add the webserver user to it:

```
sudo adduser www-data www-users
```

And give the right permissions:

```
sudo chgrp www-users /var/www
sudo chmod –R 775 /var/www
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
```

Comment: I tried the first command you said but i got the "operation not permitted" error. If this doesn't work is there any way else i can get my php projects to run under LAMP in ubuntu

Comment: @Bezaleel Are you sure you are in recovery mode? (That means, you only boot to a console, and not to any graphical login, etc.)

Comment: Yes, i made sure i choose the second option that included (recovery mode), i also had to type my login and password before i could proceed, it was all console, no GUI

Comment: @Bezaleel You never have to log in at recovery mode. See my edited post above – you need to get into the root shell prompt. You don't have to enter a password there.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the root password, type in `su -c chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers`. This should fix your issue.

The issue is most likely caused by the fact that something changed the permission value of your /etc/sudoers file to 0777, which makes it write-able by everyone, which is a major security risk. Therefore sudo denies you access, since anybody could have gained sudo access.

Comment: su -c chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
No passwd entry for user '0440'