# Group permissions for apache

Tags: fedora, apache-http-server, chmod, joomla

I've run into a problem with Joomla. . .  it cant create new folders through the Admin UI. It's a standard permissions error.  I've been told to chmod all of the folders in the site to 777.

Is there a better way to go about this? Somebody said something about creating a group and adding myself and apache into it. Then give group access to those folders. . . or something like that.

Can anybody give me any specific steps. . . I'm not that familiar doing this from the terminal ?? Or should I just chmod everything to 777 ?

Comment: What's the username/group of apache? You should probably `chgrp` the files to the `apache` group and make them writable by it. How are the permissions in `/var/www` now?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 17 root root   4096 Nov  8 16:33 www
as far as I know, apache is not in a group right now, and the username is 'apache'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> should I just chmod everything to 777?

Definitely no. This is always a security risk.

The solution is similar to [the answer I gave here](https://superuser.com/questions/350694/no-valid-sudoers-sources-found-quitting-error-while-chmodding-var-www/350720#350720). Ideally, you should create a group for all "web" users, e.g. users that need write access to `/var/www`. This would include you, `root` and `apache`.

```
sudo addgroup www-users
```

Then, you would add yourself and `apache` to this group.

```
sudo adduser <your-username> www-users
sudo adduser apache www-users
```

Finally, let's modify `/var/www` so that the new group can fully access it:

```
sudo chgrp www-users /var/www
sudo chmod –R 775 /var/www
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
```